# use same variable in multiple php files

Tags: php

There are two files which names are test1.php and test2.php.
test1.php have following lines

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
$a="test";
?>
```

test2.php have following lines

```
<?php
echo $a;
?>
```

but I can not display the $a in test2.php. What can I do to display $a value.
please anyone help.

Comment: Include the file ?

Comment: Go and learn first about session and query string. Session cannot be destroyed only on page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use $a in test2.php, you need to include test1.php in test2.php file.

```
include('test1.php');
```

Keep in mind that including test1.php is also gonna echo your 'hello world' from test1.php.

Answer (score 0):

In test2.php

```
include('test1.php');
echo $a;
```